# Can Silverlight serialize anonymous objects?

Tags: c#, silverlight, json, serialization

Can Silverlight 3 serialize anonymous objects?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No silverlight 3 can't serialize an anonymous type.  The only JSON serializer that Silverlight has is the `DataContractJsonSerializer`.  However this requires types to be decorated with the `DataContractAttribute` and members to be decorated with `DataMemberAttribute` which will not be true of anonymous types.

However if your purpose is to query some existing data and generate a JSON string output then you might consider using classes found in the `System.Json` namespace. Here is an example:-

```
/// <summary>
/// Helper methods to reduce code needed in constructing JSON items
/// </summary>
public static class JsonHelper
{       
    public static KeyValuePair<string, JsonValue> CreateProperty(string name, string value)
    {
        return new KeyValuePair<string, JsonValue>(name, new JsonPrimitive(value));
    }
    public static KeyValuePair<string, JsonValue> CreateProperty(string name, int value)
    {
        return new KeyValuePair<string, JsonValue>(name, new JsonPrimitive(value));
    }
    // Replicate above for each constructor of JsonPrimitive
    public static KeyValuePair<string, JsonValue> CreateProperty(string name, JsonValue value)
    {
        return new KeyValuePair<string, JsonValue>(name, value);
    }
}
```

The above is simply a helper static class so that the code in the following LINQ query doesn't get to hairy.  The `DataProvider` just generates some test data which in this case is a list of objects that have a `Name` property.  This noddy example simply generates a list of objects that have a `name` property and a `count` property that contains the count of characters in the name property.

```
var list = from item in DataProvider.DataItems()
        select (JsonValue)(new JsonObject(
            JsonHelper.CreateProperty("name", item.Name),
            JsonHelper.CreateProperty("count", item.Name.Length)
            ));

var result = (new JsonArray(list)).ToString();
```

Comment: Oh well, I thought this might be the case.  Too bad.  I hope they bring back JavaScriptSerializer in Silverlight, soon.

Answer (score -1):

Do you mean anonymous as in `var`?  That can't be serialized by anything.

Comment: I mean anonymous as in:
<pre><code>
new { MyProperty = "Something", MyLocation = "Somewhere" }
</code></pre>

and you can serialize it using JavaScriptSerializer in normal .Net applications, but it doesnt appear to be available in silverlight.  Too bad.  For what its worth there is no reason anonymous types cant be serialized, it's deserializing them thats the problem.